# TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python-2.7, python-datetime, python-dateutil

So I am trying to subtract to datetime object. I got one from using dateutil.parser and the other was from datetime.now(). I keep getting a

> TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

I checked for solutions but they dont seem to work. Here is the code:

```
import json
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import *

with open(".log") as dataFile: 
   dataFile.seek(0)
   data = []
   line=dataFile.readline()
   data=json.loads(line)
   data=ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(data))
   last=parser.parse(data["TIME"])
   print datetime.now()-last
```

Here is the line of data it is reading:

```
{"TIME": "2017-06-29T15:17:27.663Z"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the print to

```
print datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)-last
```

Answer (score 3):

I had that error when I was checking expire date in days on Key Vault secret. Like:

```
secret.properties.expires_on - datetime.utcnow()
```

What I had to make was:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, timezone

secret.properties.expires_on - datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

It is strange that `datetime.utcnow` didn't worked, but you know this is just IT world ;-)